# Updating an entry using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently inserting data into a table using the below method.

```
public async void PerformRegistration()
{
    var personTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<PersonTable>();

    var person = new PersonTable
    {
        FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text,
        LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text,
        EmailAddress = EmailTextBox.Text,
        Password = PasswordTextBox.Password,
        DateOfRegister = DateTime.Now
    };

    await personTable.InsertAsync(person);
}
```

And I access it like seen below

```
var person = await personTable
    .Where(p => p.EmailAddress == EmailTextBox.Text)
    .ToListAsync();
```

What is the easiest way to perform an update on an entry already in the db? I am not sure on how to keep the Id the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to load an entity like you are doing

```
var person = await personTable
    .Where(p => p.EmailAddress == EmailTextBox.Text)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then change the properties you want and after that call `UpdateAsync`

```
await personTable.UpdateAsync(person);
```

It's all explained in this [tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/)

Comment: Hi, thanks Pascal. This tutorial pointed me in the correct direction. Going to update question with the answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but without success.
I've loaded an entity like this: var namebet = await todoTable.Where(p => p.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
and called await todoTable.UpdateAsync(namebet);

But I'm stuck on changing the properties. How can change e.g FinalScore to Score.Text?