# Windows Azure - Adding data to specific row

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8

Developping a Metro Application in c# which uses Windows Azure and I have 2 problems.
I'm able to Insert a new Item but everytime I run the code I get an error:

**"An exception of type 'system.nullreferenceexception' occurred in but was not handled in user code. Additional information object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

Altough i get the error the item is saved in Azure.

**TodoItem class:**

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Private")]
    public bool Private { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstTeam")]
    public string Team1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "SecondTeam")]
    public string Team2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstBet")]
    public int Bet1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "SecondBet")]
    public int Bet2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstPlayer")]
    public string FirstPlayerName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstPlayerBet1")]
    public int FirstPlayerPronostiek1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "FirstPlayerBet2")]
    public int FirstPlayerPronostiek2 { get; set; }
}
```

Mainpage:

```
    private async void InsertTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
        items.Add(todoItem);
    }
```

Click_Event:

```
        var todoItem = new TodoItem { Text = TitelName.Text, Team1 = TeamA.Text, Team2 = TeamB.Text, Bet1 = int.Parse(ScoreTeamA.Text), Bet2 = int.Parse(ScoreTeamB.Text) };
        InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
```

**Second problem I have: On my second page I want to update a specific row (add data to the remaining columns). So I'm looking for the Id of that row and insert the data. However my Code doesn't work. Any ideas?**

Click_Event:

```
        var todoItem = new TodoItem {FirstPlayerName = TeamA.Text, FirstPlayerPronostiek1 = int.Parse(ScoreTeamA.Text), FirstPlayerPronostiek2 = int.Parse(ScoreTeamB.Text) };
        InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
```

Insert:

```
    private async void InsertTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
    {

        await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Id == int.Parse(TeamA.Text)).InsertAsync(todoItem);
        items.Add(todoItem);
       //TeamA.Text = Id from the row I want to Update

    }
```

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-data-sync/

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have existing item you do not want to **Insert** again, but **update**! It is general concept in **any** data-driven application.

For updating item check [this SO question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241996/updating-an-entry-using-azure-mobile-services)!